# How to fix 'error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist' in 3rd party Cordova android plugin

Tags: android, cordova-plugins

I updated a cordova project from 6.5 to 9 and while building the project one of the updated plugins can not find one of the android support libraries.

I have tried adding and removing both android and the plugin. I have added a libs directory and copied the missing library into it. Also I have added a plugin that does nothing but adds the library to the project. In both cases it appears that there is a conflict with an existing copy of the library. I have added all the android support libraries to my system using Android Studio.

here is the plugin line from config.xml

```
    <plugin name="com.flyingsoftgames.xapkreader" spec="@https://github.com/erobertson42/cordova-plugin-xapkreader.git#cordova-9">
...
</plugin>
```

Expected results is successful build.

Here is the error:

```
Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/johnfriedman/dev/family-portal-native/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/flyingsoftgames/xapkreader/XAPKDownloaderActivity.java:17: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to build successfully by replacing

{Project}/plugins/com.flyingsoftgames.xapkreader/src/android/XAPKDownloaderActivity.java:17

import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

with

import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;